# What does ○○に透けた mean in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning, song-lyrics

Listening to [a song](https://soundcloud.com/nakano4/sizuk), I heard these lyrics:

> はにかんだ声に透けた空はもうここにないのさ

This whole sentence is just a bit odd, but especially so because I'm not sure how to handle に + 透ける. Would something like "dissolved into" be appropriate? (e.g. "The sky, dissolved into the sound of a shy voice, isn't here anymore")

Comment: Other possible definitions of 透ける: 'shine through', 'permeate''. Does that help?

Comment: A follow-up question. Where are you getting 'dissolve' from. Are you thinking of 溶ける?

Comment: Dissolve kind of has the sense of "permeate" to me. In the moment, it was the closest word I could think of that kept the poetic tone of the song.

Answer (score 3):

AがBに透ける means "A is vaguely visible/felt through B". Commonly used in the form of AがBに透けて見える.

> - 肩ひもがシャツに透けている。
>     Shoulder straps are vaguely visible though the shirt.
> - 穏やかな声に透けて見える悪意
>     evil intention that can be felt through his gentle voice

So the line basically says this person was somehow feeling/seeing the sky through her coy voice. This is still a highly poetic and unrealistic expression, but he was even seeing God in the previous lines, after all :)

**EDIT:** @user4092's interpretation ("the sky that became transparent due to the voice") is possible, at least grammatically. But in the previous part of the song, this guy was clearly seeing/feeling God between clouds. Judging from the structure of the song, it's natural to think something similar is happening in this part, too.

Answer (score 1):

That's the same structure as 雨に濡れる: to get wet (being toughed) by rain. In other words, that に is the same as one that denote the agent or the cause in passive voice. English grammar probably doesn't allow to combine it with intransitive verbs and you can't directly translate it.

So, it says "The sky that (once) got transparent due to the shy voice isn't here anymore".

Answer (score 1):

This に means "and" basically.
We can say "はにかんだ声 and 透けた空" basically.

We have と which means "and," but this に is different from と.
In this example, はにかんだ声 comes first, then additionally 透けた空 comes next.
In other words, に shows a kind of direction.  はにかんだ声 existed, then 透けた空 existed, too.

はにかんだ声と透けた空 can be the same as 透けた空とはにかんだ声.

But, 透けた空にはにかんだ声 is different from はにかんだ声に透けた空 because はにかんだ声 is more important compared to 透けた空.

This kind of usage of に is not common, I think. I'm using the Japanese dictionary called 広辞苑. It enumerates many meanings of に, this usage is the 17th explanation.

We need to take into consider that this phrase is a part of the lyrics.  に is much better than と to rhyme with the previous line.